# Подскажите пожалуйста,мне нужно данные перевести в тип double, после умножить на 1.15 все элементы массива и вывести их в 3 столбика

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> strs = new List<string>();
        string str1;

        var file = new StreamReader(@"c:\test\Test.txt");
        while((str1 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            strs.Add(str1);
        }

        using (var saveFile = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test\Test2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var str in strs)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < strs.Count; i++)
                {
                    if ((i % 3) == 0 && (i != 0))
                    {
                        saveFile.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        saveFile.Write();
                        Console.Write();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Здравствуйте, мне нужно данные перевести в тип double, после умножить на 1.15 все элементы массива и вывести их в 3 столбика.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// получаем все строки
var strs = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test\Test.txt");
// конвертим каждую в double, умножаем на 1.15 и преобразовываем в строку
var nums = strs.Select(n => (Double.Parse(n) * 1.15).ToString()).ToArray();

var newStrs = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i += 3)
{
    // добавляем строку из 3-х параметров
    newStrs.Add(String.Join("\t", nums, i, Math.Min(nums.Length - i, 3)));
}

// записываем в файл
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\test\Test2.txt", newStrs);
```

[Потестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ibPC1i)!

Почитать:

- [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Double.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Никита обновил ответ в соответсвии с обновлением задания

Comment: Имейте в виду, что Double.Parse() может выкинуть ошибку, если строка имеет не верный формат.

Comment: А зачем вам `ToArray`, `ToString` и `List`?

Comment: @VladD по первым двум: `String.Join` принимает `string[]`. По `List` - что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @AGS17: Ну это да, но я бы тогда не пользовался `string.Join`, а сделал обыкновенный цикл `foreach`, в котором накапливал элементы по три.